# Why am I not able to copy and paste with the center button of my mouse?

Tags: xorg

I just reinstalled Kubuntu 13.10 and found that the mouse will not copy and paste after selecting and pressing the center button.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Just to mention, the function of *highlight* is not exactly *copy* and neither the function of *middle button* is not exactly *paste the content of the clipboard*. Further information: http://standards.freedesktop.org/clipboards-spec/clipboards-latest.txt

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method is to install [gpointing-device-settings](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gpointing-device-settings/)

```
sudo apt-get install gpointing-device-settings
```

You then 'use wheel emulation'

gpointing-device-settings looks as in image.

[image]